# how o fix this error i am doing crud operation there is no error but in vies file

Tags: python, django

Class 'Employee' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)

See every employee has a red line and that red line is saying what see in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng9Hk.png)

Comment: Please show your `Employee` class.

Answer (score 0):

The class you are trying to go down into, does not contain the method/task/etc. 'objects'.

You need to be sure:

1. You have the right references
2. You have spelled correctly
3. That if the class does not contain the method objects, then what does it contain(i am not sure i have used this program before, but most programs makes it as easy as entering 'Employee.' then a dropdownwindow will maybe appear to help you.

Backtrack your code and debug,